# Can't handlechange in Formik in Reach.Js

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to change `isStudent` to be true when `isStudent` is true. I tried to use handleChange and useEffect, but it is not working... How can I use `handleChange` in React Hooks + Formik.

```
  useEffect((values, setFieldValue) => {
    console.log('values', values)
    // undefined
    if(values.isStudentTicket === true) {
      setFieldValue('isStudent', true)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={enableReinitialize}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validate={validate}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      {({
        isSubmitting,
        isValid,
        setFieldValue,
        values,
      }) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <FastField
              type="checkbox"
              name="isStudent"
              onChange={handleChange}
              defaultChecked={values.isStudent}
            />
            <FastField
              type="checkbox"
              name="isStudentTicket"
              onChange={handleChange}
              defaultChecked={values.isStudentTicket}
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the logic in the `onChange` function itself

```
 <Form>
        <FastField
          type="checkbox"
          name="isStudent"
          onChange={handleChange}
          defaultChecked={values.isStudent}
        />
        <FastField
          type="checkbox"
          name="isStudentTicket"
          onChange={(e) => {
             handleChange(e); 
             if(e.target.checked === true)
                setFieldValue('isStudent', true)
          }}
          defaultChecked={values.isStudentTicket}
        />
```